# Xamarin android memory consumption grows infinitely after usage hits a certain threshold

Tags: android, memory, xamarin

I have an Xamarin android application and it seems as though when the memory usage of the app hits a certain threshold 140mb to 160mb the app will rapidly start taking up more memory as if in an infinite loop. I can see in the debugger output that the garbage collector keeps repeatedly trying to free memory but it doesn't seem to work. The memory usage will grow seemingly without bound. I watched it rise to well over 500mb of memory before I decide kill the app. I NEVER get an out of memory exception which is really weird. From what I can tell there is no specific piece of code that this happens on I can be in various screens and the same thing will occur. I have tested on multiple devices so I know its not just a problem with my device. I would attempt to show some code but I don't have any culprits.

Among the components used in my app that could maybe cause an issue are ReshSharp clients, .net Webclients, use of bitmaps, a TabHost with 3 tabs, location manager, and taking of photos through the camera. I'm stumped on this one any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
It's possible that I have narrowed down where one of the problems might be. I have a camera activity inside of a tabhost for taking photos, I have a on photo taken method that gets called after snapping a picture, after taking several photos the problem arises. Here is the method

```
    public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, global::Android.Hardware.Camera c)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        Bitmap b = BitmapExtensions.DecodeBitmapFromArray(data, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.SetRotate(RotationDegrees, WIDTH / 2f, HEIGHT / 2f);

        var bitmapScalled = Bitmap.CreateBitmap(b, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, matrix, true);

        var d = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path + "/MyApp/";
        if (!Directory.Exists(d))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(d);

        file = d + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";

        System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file);
        bitmapScalled.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 70, sw.BaseStream);
        sw.Close();

        global::Android.Locations.Location location = CameraLocationManager.GetLastKnownLocation(CameraLocationManager.GetBestProvider(new Criteria() { Accuracy = Accuracy.Fine }, true));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, typeof(EditPhotoActivity));
        intent.PutExtra("LastKnownLocation", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(LastKnownLocation));
        intent.PutExtra("Filename", file);
        //StartActivity(intent);
        StartCamera(); // restart camera preview
        b.Recycle();
        b = null;
        sw.Dispose();
        bitmapScalled.Dispose();
        bitmapScalled = null;
        // clean up
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

Comment: I would try placing the `StreamWriter` in a `using` statement and remove all `Dispose`, `Recycle` and `Collect` calls. As far as I know it's better to leave the cleanup up to the framework. Give it a try who knows it might just work. Also I'd isolate the problematic areas in a separate project just to make sure that this is indeed what causes your memory issues.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I eventually found out that Xamarin.Insights was causing the problem. I created a seperate project and I stripped all non essential code for completing the picture taking process. The problem did not occur. After fully removing all references to Xamarin Insights the problem disappeared. It is worth saying that at the time of this post Xamarin Insights is in preview and is not entirely stable. Hopefully whatever problem they have will be fixed in release.

Answer (score 3):

Although Xamarin profiler is still in preview it helped me a lot tracking down memory issues we had in our application. Reading your last comment i can confirm Xamarin Insights (v1.10.1) has a significant huge memory signature (and might even leak). After we removed it from our code - the app was behaving super fast!

Bottom line - use the profiler to identify memory issues and if you have Xamarin Insights used in your app - i suggest to remove it until further notice.